# mapping the append function to a list

Tags: python

I want to do the following elegantly. I have a list:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,1,4,7],[5],[7,8]]
```

I'd like to append the number 1 to each element of the list, so that I have

```
list1 = [[1,2,1],[3,1,4,7,1],[5,1],[7,8,1]]
```

I'm trying to map this via

```
map(list.append([1]), vectors)
```

but this returns the error `append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` and if I just try `append([1])` (without `list.`), I get `NameError: global name 'append' is not defined`. I guess I could do it with a loop, but this seems more elegant, is there a way to map this correctly?

Comment: A for-loop is fine. Map is totally wrong if what you really want is to `.append`, which is an in-place mutation.

Comment: @DarraghEnright That is very bad practice. List comprehensions are a functional construct, and you are mixing state-changes with a functional construct, it's just bad form.

Comment: Mixing `append` in-place mutations with `map` is the **opposite** of elegant.

Comment: if you absolutely want it, then use `map(lambda x: x.append(1), vectors)`. But yes, it's inelegant and actually even slower than for loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a several ways to implement what you want:

More readable and classic way

```
for el in list1:
  el.append(1)
```

List comprehension

```
list1 = [el + [1] for el in list1]
```

Generators:

```
list1 = (el + [1] for el in list1)
```

Map

```
list1 = map(lambda el: el + [1], list1)
```

What to use?

It depends on you own situation and may depends on execution speed optimizations, code readability, place of usage.

- `Map` is a worst choice in case of readability and execution speed
- `For` is a fastest and more plain way to do this
- `Generators` allows you to generate new list only when you really need this
- `List comprehension` - one liner for classic `for` and it takes advantage when you need quickly filter the new list using `if`

i.e. if you need only add element to each item - `for` loop is a best choice to do this, but if you need add `item` only if `item` > 40, then you may consider to use `List comprehension`.

**For example:**

Classic `For`

```
x = 41

for el in list1:
  if x > 40:
    el.append(x)
```

List comprehension

```
   x = 1
   list1 = [el + [x] for el in list1 if x > 40]
```

as @jmd_dk mentioned, in this sample is one fundamental difference: with simple `for` you can just *append to an existing* object of the list which makes much less impact to execution time and memory usage. When you use `List comprehension`, you will get *new list object* and in this case new list object for each item.

Comment: I disagree that the list comprehension method is a good choice here, even if we introduce some `if` condition. The expression `el + [1]` does not append to an existing list, but creates a whole new list from `el` and `[1]`. For large elements of `list1`, this will use up much more memory than needed, and most of the time would be spend on this copying. A plain for loop with an if statement inside would be the best option.

Comment: @jmd_dk here is where? I provided to author an explanation for each case and only he can decide what is best for him. in my opinion, here is enough to use simple `for`. Next, if author doesn't work with large data, then what you tell is not critical. Everything i trying to tell, it depends on situation and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension, taking advantage of the fact the adding lists concats them together.

```
new_list = [l + [1] for l in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,1,4,7],[5],[7,8]]
for el in list1:
    el.append(1)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "I guess I could do it with a loop". :)

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x: x + [1], list1)
```

you mean this?

list.append() have NO return (mean always return None)

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension and `append`, you can do:

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 1, 4, 7], [5], [7, 8]]

[item.append(1) for item in list1]
print(list1)  # Output: [[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 4, 7, 1], [5, 1], [7, 8, 1]]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 1, 4, 7], [5], [7, 8]]
>>> [item.append(1) for item in list1]
[None, None, None, None]
>>> list1
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 4, 7, 1], [5, 1], [7, 8, 1]]
```

You may also use `extend` like this:

```
[item.extend([1]) for item in list1]
print(list1)  # Output: [[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 4, 7, 1], [5, 1], [7, 8, 1]]
```